# Android how to add ScrollView

Tags: android-layout

I want to add to my application ScreenView, but i'm only getting error.

My layout:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    tools:context=".NwActivity" android:baselineAligned="false">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rlA" >

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/teamA"
                android:text="@string/teamA"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                style="@style/Txt" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pAddA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/teamA"
                style="@style/Txt"
                android:text="@string/pAdd"
                android:onClick="addA" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eta0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/pAddA"
                style="@style/Txt"
                android:hint="@string/pHint" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rlB" >

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/teamB"
                android:text="@string/teamB"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                style="@style/Txt" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pAddB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/teamB"
                style="@style/Txt"
                android:text="@string/pAdd"
                android:onClick="addB" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
package some.program;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class NwActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nw);
    }

    public int skid = 0;

    public void addA(View view) {
        if(skid < 14) {
            skid = skid + 1;
            //LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlA);

            EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
            et1.setHint(R.string.pHint);
            String strID = "eta" + skid;
            int nid = getResources().getIdentifier(strID, "id", this.getPackageName());
            et1.setId(nid);

            int oskid = skid - 1;

            int oid;


            String resID = "eta" + oskid;
            oid = getResources().getIdentifier(resID, "id", this.getPackageName());


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                        ( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, oid);
            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            et1.setLayoutParams(params1);
            et1.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.Txt);
            rl.addView(et1);
        }
    }

    public void addB(View view) {

    }

}
```

How can i add ScrollView, that will not make mess on my layout? When clicking Button, app is creating EditText forms. Everything works fine, but all EditText fields don't fit on layout and don't appear.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please show the logCat.

Comment: a scrollview cannot have more than 1 child

Answer (score 0):

There may be some other issues in your layout, some of the issues which I have found are

Firstly `ScrollView` only takes one direct child, while you are declaring two views rlA and rlB in `ScrollView`. (You can make it working by putting `ScrollView` as your main layout and putting `LinearLayout` in place of `ScrollView`)

Secondly you should add `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes for your layouts (I guess you are already declaring in your ***STYLES***).

Comment: Yes, i declare width and height in Txt style. Worked fine when i replaced ScrollView and LinearLayout. Is it possible to make, that when I click on button app scroll down? (Sorry for my bad english)